# Using Indexes results in Update locks cannot be acquired during a READ UNCOMMITTED transaction

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

After upgrading to mariadb 10.5.11 I ran into a weird problem with the indexes.

Simple table with two colums `Type`(varchar) and `Point`(point)

An index on `Type`(Tindex) and a spatial index on `Point`(Pindex)

Now a query like

```
SELECT X(Point) as x,Y(Point) as y,hotels.Type FROM hotels WHERE (Type in ("acco")) AND MBRContains( GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(4.922 52.909,5.625 52.483)' ), hotels.Point)
;
```

Results in a

Error in query (1207): Update locks cannot be acquired during a READ UNCOMMITTED transaction

While both

```
SELECT X(Point) as x,Y(Point) as y,hotels.Type FROM hotels USE INDEX (Pindex) WHERE (Type in ("acco")) AND MBRContains( GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(4.922 52.909,5.625 52.483)' ), hotels.Point)
;
```

and

```
SELECT X(Point) as x,Y(Point) as y,hotels.Type FROM hotels USE INDEX (Tindex) WHERE (Type in ("acco")) AND MBRContains( GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(4.922 52.909,5.625 52.483)' ), hotels.Point)
;
```

work fine. As mariadb 10.5.10 did

| id   | select_type | table  | type         | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                           |

|    1 | SIMPLE      | hotels | range|filter | Type,Pindex   | Pindex|Type | 34|302  | NULL | 340 (4%) | Using where; Using rowid filter |

Answer (score 2):

The issue is now being tracked as [MDEV-26123](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26123) (I guess you reported it there). The issue description says that the problem was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.39, 10.3.30, 10.4.20, 10.5.11, 10.6.1.

I ran into the issue after upgrading to MariaDB 10.6.4. I downgraded to 10.6.0, which was possible without having to do any migration of the data. It seems to have fixed the problem for now.

Comment: I just delete the old index, then, create a new one with different name, magically the error is gone ... dunno why

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this appears to be the [code fix](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/b9a2e4609f93f2cab253f02bc7535960852de3c5) for [MDEV-25594](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25594).

I cannot see anything in the commit message or discussion there that indicates that a change to the READ UNCOMMITTED behavior was intentional.

There are no open bug reports on this so I recommend you create a [new bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa).

Comment: MDEV-26123: Fixing this bug is not trivial. I fear that the locking for {{SPATIAL INDEX}} would need to be redesigned altogether.

Answer (score 1):

select @@session.autocommit;

set @@session.autocommit=0;

select @@session.autocommit;

#add in my.cnf
autocommit                = 0

using mariadb 10.2.40 ( resolved )
https://developpaper.com/transaction-isolation-level-of-mariadb/